# Json Result From MVC With Ajax Is Not Showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

My Ajax block looks like so:

```
    $('#btnTest').click(function(){
      $.getJSON('/User/ViewMessages',function(result) {
            // TODO: update the DOM with the items
            $("table#tblMessages").append("<tr><td>"+result.MESSAGETEXT+"</td><td>"+result.DATESENT+"</td>");
      });
    });
```

My Action in my Controller looks like such:

```
        public ActionResult ViewMessages()
    {
        var recipient = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session["User_Id"]);
        var query = (from m in context.Messages
                     from rec in context.Recipients
                     where rec.RECIPIENT == recipient
                     where rec.MESSAGEID == m.MESSAGEID
                     select new 
                     {
                         m.MESSAGETEXT,
                         m.DATESENT
                     }).ToList();
        return Json(query.ToList());
    }
```

When Debugging, my query variable returns:
{ MESSAGETEXT = "seresr", DATESENT = {9/15/2011 11:06:45 AM} }

The thing is, my table is added with "undefined" for both my  values. Where have i gone wrong? I have already added the maproute as well, but I'm still out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're returning a list, which will be represented in JSON as an array.  So your `result` object is a JavaScript array rather than a single object.  To loop through all the items and add a table row for each, try something like this:

```
$.getJSON('/User/ViewMessages', function(result) {
    for (var i in result) {
        var row = result[i];
        $("table#tblMessages").append("<tr><td>" + row.MESSAGETEXT
            + "</td><td>" + row.DATESENT + "</td>");
    }
});
```